# Eclipse c++ autocomplete does not work, despite finding headers

Tags: c++, eclipse, autocomplete

Eclipse auto-complete in C++ is not working for me. I've googled around, and these issues almost always seem to come back to Eclipse not finding definitions for things. But for me, this is not the case. For instance, when I type in the name of an object followed by '.', no auto complete is offered, even when I try to force when ctrl+space. However, after I type in the correct method name, I can F3 it, and it correctly brings me to the definition. This is the case for both standard library objects/methods (eg std::vector) and objects within my own source code. What gives?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if your content assist preferences are turned off.
You might want to check the preferences: [C/C++ > Editor > Content assist](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_c_editor_con_assist.htm) and check whatever you deem useful.

Comment: In the area you described, everything is checked off.